# C# SQL to LINQ pattern matching

Tags: c#, sql, linq

In my database i have table what contains a file name pattern.

Pattern in database:

`PKO??_??_??????_*.TXT`

File name:

```
PKO10_11_123456_example.TXT
```

Now when some file is imported to my program i need to match it against these patterns in database. I know that `Directory.GetFiles()` has this option to add the pattern and it give back all the files what will match with this patter. Is there a way i can do that in LINQ query? I tried `Containes()` like this:

```
 var _cardType = (from type in context.OCA_CARD_TYPEs
     where type.FILENAME.ToLower().Contains(fileName.ToLower())
     select type).Single();
```

But like that i didnt get any match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
where System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlMethods.Like(
         type.FILENAME.ToUpper(), filename, '\\')
```

with `filename` as `@"PKO__\___\_______\_%.TXT"`

and note that the `\_` are the **literal** `_` (escaped via the `\` character we specified) - the `_` and `%` are the `LIKE` wildcards akin to `?` and `*` respectively.

Comment: In my case `filename` is the full name of the file and patterns are stored in database.

Comment: @hs2d "and patterns are stored in database" so? just load them up, translate them to what SQL needs (`_` and `%`, taking escape characters into account), and use it... about 3 calls to `string.Replace` should do it...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that `?` is a placeholder in Transact-SQL. To match a single char use `_`. Then you also need to escape your underscores. I don't know how L2S or L2E behave in that.

[More](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms179859.aspx)